# Using OpenCV2.2 with Code::Blocks 10.05. Error: ld.exe cannot find -lhighgui

Tags: linker, opencv, codeblocks

I'm trying to build a simple webcam application in C++. I'm using wxWidget for GUI and OpenCV for image and video operations. But I'm having trouble setting up OpenCV on my IDE. When i try to run a sample code, or any code for that matter, I get an error that says:

ld.exe cannot find -lhighgui

I'v properly given the library and include links to the IDE. OpenCV's path is also added, I checked. I even tried linking each library file individually but id didnt work.

Please Help. :)

I'm using Windows 7 Professional X64 and Code::Blocks 10.05

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

--Aayush Shrestha

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV library files have been renamed with version 2.2. You can link to the new library  `opencv_highgui` instead of `highgui`.

You also need to do this for other OpenCV libraries you use.